# Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript throw error about my code:

> Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'null'.(2322)

```
const model = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: null,
};

if (true) {
  model.baz = true; // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'null'.(2322)
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nnubaj?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json)

I want to initial the `baz` property later in `if` statement.

Can I do it without create interface for the `model`? because `model` just temporary variable.

Comment: TypeScript works best by far when you create everything at once without mutation, in my experience. Consider if there's any way to restructure your code so you can create the model in one go once you know what `baz` should be.

Comment: `boolean` datatype can only have `true` or `false` statement, nothing more, nothing less. You either have to define `model.baz` with one of this two values or create an interface that combines `boolean` with `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without repeating yourself or creating an interface by using `as` to assert that the `baz` property, despite having `null` assigned to it, can be `null | boolean`.

```
const model = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: null as null | boolean,
};

if (true) {
  model.baz = true;
}
```

That said, I'll repeat my comment:

> TypeScript works best by far when you create everything at once without mutation, in my experience. Consider if there's any way to restructure your code so you can create the model in one go once you know what `baz` should be.

Answer (score 0):

use interface to tell compiler what type of model is

```
interface Model {
   foo: boolean,
   bar: boolean,
   baz: boolean | null,
}
const model: Model = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false,
  baz: null,
};
if (true){
  model.baz = true;
}
```